# Angular 2 AuthHttp with jwt not connecting

Tags: api, angular, jwt

I'm trying to use jwt's authHttp to set an API connection to a particular Back End. I'm trying to make it first without any token so I can test it but it seams like it's not even getting connected. I'm using it as following:

```
  this.authHttp.get('localhost:3001/api/basic')
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log("data"),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Request Complete')
  );
```

The error I'm getting in the console is `AuthHttpError {}`

I've set my ngModules as it say in the guide:

```
  providers: [
{
  provide: AuthHttp,
  useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
  deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
}
```

And

```
function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({noTokenScheme : true}), http);
}
```

The thing that drive's me crazy is that using http it works fine like this:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/basic').subscribe(
  data=> console.log(data),
  error=> console.log("Getting Error") 
);
```

You are probably thinking "Why he is not using http then instead of authHttp?". Well, that's because setting a heather "Authorization" and its token seams impossible with http.

Any help or guidance would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What type of `Authorization` headers do you need ? this library is made for JWT tokens, so not using them with it is impossible. I'll post an answer with examples in the meantime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't **need** JsonWebTokens but simply want to add custom headers, you can do it this way without having to import the `angular2-jwt` library :

In your service :

```
private customHeaders: Headers = this.setCredentialsHeader();

setCredentialsHeader() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let credentials = window.localStorage.getItem('credentials2');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials);
    return headers;
}

someMethod() {
  let url = 'your.URL.to.API';

  return this.http
    .get(url, { headers: this.customHeaders })
    .map(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
}
```

This way you can add your `Authorization` header with the type of data you want.

---

If it's a `Authorization` `Bearer` type header you are looking for and use it with `angular2-jwt`, you can use the default configuration first before trying to provide your own AuthHttp instance through the factory. It will be much simpler to debug and figure where the problem is.

From the documentation : https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#configuration-options

> `AUTH_PROVIDERS` gives a default configuration setup:

In your module with your service, just import the `AUTH_PROVIDERS` like this :

```
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AUTH_PROVIDERS,
    ...
  ]
})
```

and simply use the `AuthHttp` instance in your service like you did.

You should see in the Navigator Network tab your headers being added to your request.

**EDIT :**

As stated in the documentation, it is appending the token value in the headers from the `Token Getter Function` defined in the `AUTH_PROVIDERS` by default.

You therefore need to add your JWT in your `LocalStorage` with the default name `id_token`.

To give you my working example, I'm setting a JWT upon the authentication process, where I get a JWT as a response from my Http Call :

**auth.service.ts**

```
  this.identityService.setToken(token.accessToken);
```

**identity.service.ts**

```
  setToken(token?) {
    if (token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    } else {
      window.localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    }
  }
```

You should be able to see your JWT in your network tab if done correctly.
Afterwards, the AuthHttp instance should add the headers to your requests as intended...

It might not work correctly if your Token is not a JWT. To check if it's a good one, you can use a website such as https://jwt.io/ where it will be decoded.

If it's still not working, this means the problem is coming from elsewhere. A service not provided correctly, etc.

Comment: It's a Authorization Bearer what I need. I've imported AUTH_PROVIDERS as you've said but it's not not doing any call. When looking in the Navigator Network tab there is nothing. In the console I'm still getting the AuthHttpError.

Comment: I've tried the http way by setting the Authorization header but when checking in the NAvigatior Network tab it seams like the header is not setted. I've done it with:
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ${pass}'); 

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/outputEndpoints', {
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe(
      data=> console.log(data),
      error=> console.log("Getting Error") 
    );
  }

Comment: BTW, when setting the header with http I'm getting the following message: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: This is an issue with CORS, because your server is not allowing Cross Domain requests. You need to fix that from the server. I'll edit my question concerning the AUTH_PROVIDERS

Comment: But If I try to make this call with CURL or SOAP UI or similar and it works. Does it change from that to an app?

Comment: In this post I've explained with more details the header setting part. It may be helpful to understand it  -- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118733/angular-2-http-not-setting-header

Comment: Updated the answer. I can't give that much more time, I'll look into it tomorrow if you still struggle =)

Comment: I've tried the last solution but it's still not working.... Any other idea?

Comment: We might need other information with the issue then. Did you try step by step ? Do you have an `id_token` in your localStorage ? Are there no error with providers or anything from your service ? Are you sure this is a JWT you store and is it valid (post a sample so we can see it) ? Can you also provide a screenshot of your AuthHttp Call headers as well ? Maybe it's just some typing problem as well