# Angular 2 http not setting header

Tags: angular, http-headers

I'm setting my header and http call like this:

```
 var headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Authorization','Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx'); 

this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/outputEndpoints', {
  headers: headers
}).
map(res => res.text())

.subscribe(
  data=> console.log(data),
  error=> console.log("Getting Error") 
);
```

With this I'm expected the header to be:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:es,ca;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
Authorization: "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxx"
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:3000
 Referer:http://localhost:3000/
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Instead I'm getting the following (no Authorization with the token):

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:es,ca;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

**EDIT:**

The general info is:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/outputEndpoints
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
```

So the OPTIONS call is failing. In other apps, once the OPTIONS call is accepted it makes the GET request in where you can find the Authentication token setted. That means that for some reason the OPTION call it's not being accepted.

When making calls with CURL or SOAP UI it works fine so I presume that it's not a problem with CORS. I'am right?

Any idea or guide would be really helpful.

Comment: did you find the solution? same problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this guide http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/ you can read the following:

> An important comment. You must take into account that, when executing
>   CORS request containing security, i.e. an Authorization header, the
>   OPTIONS request won’t contain it. So you need to be careful regarding
>   security when handling the first OPTIONS requests of preflighted ones.
>   As a matter of fact, no authentication check can be done at this
>   level.

So there is no Authorization header in the first OPTION call.

Comment: but how did you solve it ? can you show the code?, I get error from my server, not from postman or curl, just with angular 4.1.2

Comment: api programmer told me that OPTIONS must have authorisation code, so the api works like that, but my browser dont send OPTIONS with auth, how to force my browser to do it ?

Comment: If there is no jwt authorization, it will send a normal request without the OPTIONS

Answer (score 2):

I think it is `headers.append` and not `headers.set`. Try to change your method and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried both and non of them work. When printing the header option it seams to be ok but when I check it in the network tab it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

You should either set the value in the constructor of the Header like this:

```
var headers = new Headers({'Authorization', 'Bearer XXXXXXX'});
```

or you have to use the append method:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer XXXXXX');
```

Edited due to changed question:

Since I do not really know how you handle your request I can show you the solution I came up with in my Spring backend:

```
if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.method, ignoreCase = true)) {
    response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
} else {
    chain.doFilter(req, res)
}
```

So in your backend you should check the request method and if it equals "OPTIONS" than you can set the response status to 200 and you are done.

Comment: I've used all the known ways (the constructor, append and set) and none of them work. When printing the header in the console it seams to be working fine but in the navigation tab there is no Authorization header (as it's shown in the console)

Comment: As I've extended in the question, It's not going trough the OPTIONS call but the header is correctly setted. The problem then is why is failing in the first OPTIONS call.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your security configuration:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
```